# 400 (Bad Request) при от правке данных на Spring контроллер

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Хочу отправить данные с jquery на java controller

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/saveMeeting",
        type: "POST",
        data: {name:$("#inputName").val(), place:$("#inputPlace").val(), date:$("#inputDate").val(), criteria: criteria, groups:group},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (textStatus) {
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

тут `name`, `place` и `date` - строки, а `criteria` и `group` - массивы строк.

контроллер:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/saveMeeting", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String saveMeeting(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String place, @RequestParam String date,
                          @RequestParam List<String> criteria, @RequestParam List<String> groups) {
    System.out.println(name+" "+place+" "+date+" "+criteria+" "+groups);
    return "success";
}
```

при отправке получаю ошибку:

> HTTP Status 400 - Required List parameter 'criteria' is not present.

Если не отправлять последние 2 массива, то всё нормально приходит. Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить?

**UPD**

Переделал с одним объектом:

```
var Dto = {name:$("#inputName").val(), place:$("#inputPlace").val(),   date:$("#inputDate").val(), criterions: criteria, groups:group};
    $.ajax({
        url: "/saveMeeting",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({newCriteriaDto: Dto}),
        dataType:'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (textStatus) {
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

Поменял контроллер на

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/saveMeeting", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String saveMeeting(@RequestBody NewCriteriaDto newCriteriaDto) {
        System.out.println(newCriteriaDto);
    return "success";
}
```

Ошибка исчезла, но когда пытаюсь вывести `newCriteriaDto`, его поля не инициализированы (null).

Comment: что в логах пишет? что за ексепшн?

Comment: @Виктор, добавил в первый пост

Comment: ну и HTTP Status 400 - Required List parameter 'criteria' is not present

Comment: что в логах пишет когда вы отправляете с массивами? Это вы отправили без них вам тут так и написало "Required List parameter 'criteria' is not present"

Comment: это с массивами

Comment: `@RequestParam` не для query string ли используется? В любом случае будет удобнее сделать одну структуру, которую получать как `@ResponseBody`

Comment: @Etki, поменял на ResponseBody, ошибка исчезла, но его поля не инициализированы..

Comment: имеется в виду поля newCriteriaDto не инициализированы.